# Basic Form validation and insert to database

Tags: php, validation, insert, laravel-5

I am working on a project on my own using Laravel 5.2

I'm at the registration form validation and insert to database process.

Route:

```
Route::post('/register', 'UserController@create');
```

UserController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Crypt;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(CreateUserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->all() = User::all();
        $user->password = Crypt::encrypt($user->password);
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

CreateUserRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        'username' => 'required|regex:[a-zA-Z0-9]+|between:3,12|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|regex:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

When I'm submitting my completed form, it won't insert the new user in database. I know I have to do a redirect at the end, but I'm just trying to insert the new user in the users table.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: There is my register form in case there's a problem in there.

```
                    <form method="POST" action="/register">                     
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fw fa-user"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" required
                                                                                                                    minlength="3"
                                                                                                                    maxlength="12"
                                                                                                                    data-validation-regex-regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
                                                                                                                    data-validation-regex-message="Votre nom d'utilisateur doit comporter entre 3 et 12 caractères alphanumériques."
                                                                                                                    data-validation-minlength-message="Votre nom d'utilisateur doit comporter entre 3 et 12 caractères alphanumériques.">
                        </div>
                        <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Ce nom d'utilisateur sert à vous identifier et sera visible sur le forum. Ce n'est pas votre nom en jeu. Votre nom doit contenir entre 3 et 12 caractères alphanumériques.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Courriel</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fw fa-envelope"></i></div>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com"  required
                                                                                                                    data-validation-email-message="Votre adresse courriel doit être valide afin de compléter votre inscription.">
                        </div>
                        <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Votre adresse courriel doit être valide afin de compléter votre inscription.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Mot de passe</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fw fa-lock"></i></div>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"  required
                                                                                                                    minlength="6"
                                                                                                                    data-validation-regex-regex="(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+"
                                                                                                                    data-validation-minlength-message="Votre mot de passe doit comporter au moins 6 caractères alphanumériques dont minimum une lettre majuscule et un chiffre."
                                                                                                                    data-validation-regex-message="Votre mot de passe doit comporter au moins 6 caractères alphanumériques dont minimum une lettre majuscule et un chiffre.">
                        </div>
                        <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Votre mot de passe doit comporter au moins 6 caractères alphanumériques dont minimum une lettre majuscule et un chiffre.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Confirmation du mot de passe</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fw fa-lock"></i></div>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Mot de passe" required
                                                                                                                    data-validation-match-match="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcrSRgTAAAAAJ5RbvAlBMZ20OPrI_UYjtLFjqic"></div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="eula" required> J'ai lu et j'accepte les <a>conditions générales d'utilisation</a>.
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fw fa-user-plus"></i> S'inscrire</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public function create(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],            
        'email' => $data['email'],
        //Here you put all your user fields like lastname and username above
        ...                    
        'password' => Crypt::encrypt($data['password']),
        ...                                   
      ]);        
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this right now. However, isn't there supposed to be a save() or something?

Comment: Same, but this one is  cute :)

Comment: Let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: I tried it, but it won't insert the user in the table.

Comment: Ok, what's the error message when you try to insert ?

Comment: On your browser, click Ctrl + shift + Q , then click on console, retry your insert and tell me the error (see red line in console)

Comment: Actually, there is no error. It's like when I click on the submit button on the form, it won't do anything. My form has method="POST" and action="/register". I really don't understand what's going on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My submit button:
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fw fa-user-plus"></i> S'inscrire</button>
Which is before the </form> tag. It should be working, but it's not. What the hell.

Comment: Insert this code : <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
after <form method ... > line

Comment: I added the token hidden field. Won't change a thing. I disabled JavaScript and tried again. It throws a laravel error: Class App\Http\Controllers\CreateUserRequest does not exist

Comment: Oh noooooo finally you found the problem hhhh 
So, go to App/Http/Requests folder and create file CreateUserRequest.php and put its code you set in the post

Comment: Well, the problem is there's already a CreateUserRequest.php in App\Http\Requests... Why would Laravel send a ReflectionException? That's so weird!

Comment: I will make another question with this problem.

Comment: I had a couple of stupid errors in my files, such as not including the Request file in the UserController, or missing ; somewhere in the Eloquent User Model. Everything work fine now. I just have to understand why the regex patterns don't work in the CreateUserRequest.

Comment: Good, happy to help you :)
For regex, please see this link may help you
http://laravelbook.com/laravel-input-validation/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, BKF.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete) which is about how to insert data into a database.

```
 public function create(CreateUserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->all() = User::all();
        $user->password = Crypt::encrypt($user->password);
        $user->save();
    }
```

In the above function what you have done is ,

```
$user = new User;
```

will make a new user model object

```
 $user->all() = User::all();
```

will call a user model all method to retrieve data from database. And

```
$user->password = Crypt::encrypt($user->password);
```

will update the password field of your table with the password field of your table .

At last

```
$user->save();
```

will try to save the data with the updated values. But you are trying to insert new user into db right ?? So, you can simply do something like this :

```
    public function create(CreateUserRequest $request){
$user = new User;
    $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->password = Crypt::encrypt($request->password');
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried both your solution and BKF's one. None are working, there must be another problem somewhere else. You can read the comments below his answer. Thanks!